# Command prompt changing characters in pasted text

Tags: character-encoding, console, special-characters, paste

I'm writing a C# console application, and whenever I paste text that contains double quotation marks into the console, it changes them to a regular quotation mark.
Here's an example: 
I paste `„Hello World!”` into the console, but it displays `„Hello World!"` instead. I tried changing the input and output enconding to unicode, but it didn't help. Pasting into notepad works just fine.

Comment: To which unicode encoding did you changed the console?

Comment: Encoding.UNICODE

Comment: Unicode is not an encoding, encodings for unicode are for example utf-8, utf-16, etc.

Comment: I tried UTF-8 and ASCII, they didn't do anything. UTF-32 threw an error.

Comment: try utf-16, C# strings are encoded in utf-16 maybe that is the problem. If not try to create an [mre] so we can check it our self

Comment: I am sceptic about your code because it works for me [tio.run](https://tio.run/##NYu9CsIwEIDn5inOrR30BYqTi4OC1KGDOBzpUQJpDu5iQaTQF9GH64vEVHD9fqxuLQul9FAXerg@NdJQG@tRFS7CveAAL1NoxOgsjOw6OKMLpUbJw@0OKL1Wa1KMKJAx7OHAQdnTriHsTi5QWdXZ/2krLtIP53o1k5lSWubPkbxnaFl8t1nmt/kC)

Comment: Yes, it works if you type the input text yourself, but if you copy and paste in the console, it will change to what I said. https://imgur.com/a/8vDDbD1

Comment: Alright I get the problem, but it seems that the console just recognizes the `”` and converts it to `"` since they convey the same meaning. This is definitly a problem of the cmd, for example if I paste the string into a powershell console it gets converted to `"Hello World!"`.

Comment: Also please remove the C# tag since it clearly has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found solution for pure `cmd` window as well as for a console application if run by double click from File Explorer. There is a *DWORD* value 
 named `FilterOnPaste` under registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`. Defaults to `1` (1 *enables new paste behavior*), **change it to `0`**.

Check

```
reg query HKCU\Console -v FilterOnPaste
```

and if you get default data

> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console
>     FilterOnPaste    REG_DWORD    0x1
> ```

or *ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value* then **run**

```
reg add HKCU\Console -v FilterOnPaste -d 0 -t REG_DWORD -f
```

> ```
> The operation completed successfully.
> ```

An explanation at [What's New in the Windows Console in Windows Server 2016 => Controlling the new features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/whats-new-in-console#controlling-the-new-features) (valid for *Windows 10* console as well).

Another explanation for a `cmd` shortcut settings with screenshots at [How to enable the new console in Windows 10 and what are its defaults?](https://superuser.com/a/954426/376602).

Actually I can't understand full meaning and consequences of *new paste behavior*.

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think you have to re-open console for this change to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that the answer to this question by @JosefZ for some reason didn't work for me (maybe reboot or signing out is required), however setting `reg add HKCU\Console -v ForceV2 -d 0 -t REG_DWORD -f` to temporary disable all new V2 features of Command Prompt (as described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/954426/1689619)) has helped.